# Copy constructor for the class in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I want to write a copy constructor for the `Plane` class.

```
class Widget{ };
class Button: public Widget{};
class Label: public Widget {};
class Plane {
   vector<Widget*>vec;
public:
   void Add (Widget* w) {
      vec.push_back(w);
   }
// need to implement copy constructor for this class???
//Plane (const Plane &obj) ???
~Plane() {
   for (auto w: vec) {
      delete w;
     }
  }
};

int main () {
   Plane p1;
   p1.Add(new Button);
   p1.Add(new Label);
   Plane p2(p1);
   return 0;
}
```

Need your help to write a copy constructor for `class Plane`. Do I also need to change something in the `Widget class` as well? I want to have a deep copy and that's why a copy constructor is required here. I tried to write the copy constructor by myself but failed.

Comment: `Plane` is not a derived class. What do you mean in the title?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not here to write the code for people, but to answer questions or solve problems with the code they have already attempted.

Comment: Perhaps you need `virtual Widget* Widget::Clone();`.

Comment: If you add code demonstrating what you have already attempted, or can show error messages from your attempt, I will rescind my close vote. Give us an example of how you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Your `Plane` is already not safe with this destructor: you have vector of Widget pointers, but these cannot be shared due to the destructor killing them all. The correct way is to have a vector of unique_ptr<Widget> or shared_ptr<Widget>, in which case you don't need destructor, and the copy constructor is either not allowed or automatic. Or, you need to know how to (virtually) copy the Widget instance.

Comment: @freakish , yes I want a deep copy and that's why copy constructor is required for the ```Plane class```.

Comment: "I tried to write the copy constructor by myself but failed." is not a specific question. You seem to know you want a deep copy. So figure out the individual steps for doing that conceptually, and then try writing the code. If you have a problem, then show that code and describe what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I'd use `unique_ptr<Widget>` since it is an owning smart pointer.  Rather than `Widget*` raw pointer, which does not manage the life-cycle of the object (you have to do that manually... ick ick).  You'll need some way for a polymorphic Widget to "clone" or "dup" itself.  You'll have to handle (or `=delete`) Plane's copy constructor, copy assignment, move constructor, move assignment, since you have resources that need deep copying (or move swapping).

Comment: If `Plane` were also a `Widget`, the code would be an example of the Composite pattern.

Comment: @PravejKhan They want you to insert code for a copy constructor of `Plane`,  just modify your code to include a standard one which cannot perform deep copy, for instance `Plane (const Plane &obj) { vec = (*obj).vec;}`.

Comment: `Widget` hierarchy misses virtual destructors and other virtual functions. You cannot work with `vector<Widget*>` without those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you decided to use raw pointers instead of `unique_ptr`s.

`unique_ptr`s have RAII functionality, meaning when going out of scope they automatically destroy, along with the pointer, the resource pointed-to.

With raw pointers instead, you are required to `delete` them manually. In addition, if you employ them as data members in a custom class, you are also required to define your own `copy`&`move` constructors and assignment operators.

A `clone()` method (which in Java I hear is infamous, much less so in C++) would allow you to perform deep copy of the `vector<Widget*>` as you require for your code.

The program should work if modified as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::move;
using std::exception;
using std::logic_error;

class Widget
{
public:
    Widget() {cout << "created Base Widget\n";}
    Widget(const Widget& original) noexcept {
        cout << "copied Base Widget\n";
    }

    virtual ~Widget(){} // need virtual destructor with class hierarchy

    virtual Widget* clone() const { // makes deep copies of pointers
        if constexpr(noexcept(Widget(*this))) {
            try {
                cout << "cloned Widget\n";
                return new Widget(*this);
            } 
            catch(exception& e) {
                throw runtime_error("error occurred while cloning Widget");
            }
        } else 
            throw logic_error("Widget: Faulty constructor");           
    }
};

class Button: public Widget{
public:
    Button(): Widget() { cout << "created Button\n"; }
    Button(const Button& original) noexcept: Widget(original){ 
        cout << "copied Button\n";
    }
    
    virtual Button* clone() const {
        if constexpr(noexcept(Button(*this))) {
            try {
                cout << "cloned Button\n";
                return new Button(*this);
            } 
            catch(exception& e) {
                throw runtime_error("error occurred while cloning Button");
            }
        } else 
            throw logic_error("Button: Faulty constructor");           
    }
    
    virtual ~Button(){}
};

class Label: public Widget {
public:
    Label(): Widget() { cout << "created Label\n"; }
    Label(const Label& original) noexcept: Widget(original){
        cout << "copied Label\n";
    }
    
    virtual Label* clone() const {
        if constexpr(noexcept(Label(*this))) {
            try {
                cout << "cloned Label\n";
                return new Label(*this);
            } 
            catch(exception& e) {
                throw runtime_error("error occurred while cloning Label");
            }
        } else 
            throw logic_error("Label: Faulty constructor");
    }
    
    virtual ~Label(){}
};

class Plane { // destructor is needed so copy&move semantics are also needed
              // (rule of 5)
    vector<Widget*>vec;
public:
    Plane(): vec(0) {}

    Plane(const Plane& original)  // performs deep copy
    {   
        vec.resize(original.vec.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i != original.vec.size(); ++i) 
            vec[i] = original.vec[i]->clone();
    }

    Plane& operator=(const Plane& original)
    {   
        if (this != &original) {
            vec.resize(original.vec.size());
            for (size_t i = 0; i != original.vec.size(); ++i) 
                vec[i] = original.vec[i]->clone();
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~Plane() {
        for (auto w: vec) {
            delete w;
            cout << "deleted Widget\n";
        }
    }

    // for completeness also add move semantics
    Plane(Plane&& original) noexcept
    {
        vec = move(original.vec);
        cout << "moved Plane\n";
    }

    Plane& operator=(Plane&& original) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &original)
            vec.swap(original.vec);

        return *this;
    }

    void Add (Widget* w) {
        vec.push_back(w);
        cout << "added Widget*\n";
    }
};

int main () {
   Plane p1;
   p1.Add(new Button);
   p1.Add(new Label);
   Plane p2(p1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Results as expected: four `Widget`s are `delete`d (two in `p1` and two in `p2`)

```
created Base Widget
created Button
added Widget*
created Base Widget
created Label
added Widget*
cloned Button
copied Base Widget
copied Button
cloned Label
copied Base Widget
copied Label
deleted Widget
deleted Widget
deleted Widget
deleted Widget
```

Comment: Without `std::unique_ptr` this is also not exception-safe. If allocation/construction of one of the cloned elements throws, then the already-cloned ones will be leaked.

Comment: Also a minor point, but `auto i = 0` is not really correct. Using `auto` works if counting down to deduce the correct type from the result of `size`, but this `auto` always deduces `int` which may be too small to hold the size, in which case it will overflow with undefined behavior.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you. Added `try ... catch` construct in `clone()` and changed that `auto` loop index to `size_t`.

Comment: Unfortunately the `try`/`catch` doesn't do anything to really resolve the issue. If there is an exception the copy will be incomplete. Correctly adding exception-safety requires catching the exception in the `for` loop calling `clone` and then iterating over all elements at index smaller than the current `i` to call `delete` on them, then rethrowing the exception. Because that is rather complicated it shouldn't be done manually. If `std::vector` is used together with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` instead of `new` from the start, then this would work correctly automatically.

Comment: @user17732522 can the `for` loop possibly throw because `original.vec.size()` may overflow? Also, since C++11, `operator new` seem to be `noexcept` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new at least in more than a few cases (5-10 among those in the link). How could anyone still use the old throwing `new`s? More than a decade old modules available only already precompiled?

Comment: @user17732522 But I get it, `new` is taken care of already (by the `try...catch`). You are worried mainly over the loop in the function calling `clone()`, that may `throw`.

Comment: No exception will be thrown if `original.vec.size()` overflows `int`. The overflowing increment in the loop will just have undefined behavior at that point. But you fixed that issue correctly by using `size_t`. There are always two versions of the relevant allocating `operator new`, one `noexcept` and the other not. A `new` expression without a `std::nothrow` placement-argument will always use the throwing one. But not only the allocation can throw. The constructor could (not here but in typical scenarios) also throw.

Comment: The point is that while your approach avoids the memory leak it will still potentially construct a copy with some of the elements set to zero instead of a correct copy. In most scenarios that is probably an invalid state that shouldn't occur. Instead the constructor should rethrow, which is why the approach I described is required. But all of this is only relevant if you actually use exceptions or care about allocation failures (which are often handled by just terminating the program anyway). It is so easy to avoid these problems though all-together with the right standard library tools.

Comment: @user17732522 how about now: I have labelled the constructor `noexcept`, then added an `if constexpr` in `clone()` to terminate the program at compile time in case the constructor were different, and could instead `throw`.

Comment: You made the wrong constructor `noexcept`. It should be the copy constructor. Also if your `constexpr` check fails, then the clone method simply doesn't work anymore. I also just noticed that your `catch` handler is missing a `return nullptr;` or something of that kind. Otherwise the function is flowing off the body, causing undefined behavior. The compiler should be warning you about this. None of this really helps though because a derived class might be using a throwing constructor. You would need to forbid this for all derived classes as well. (I think your original code was better.)

Comment: I also just noticed that you didn't implement `clone` in the derived classes. You need to do that, otherwise you are not creating copies of the correct type with `clone`. On the other hand you don't need to declare the virtual destructor in the derived classes again.

Comment: @user17732522 I have inverted the order of `if constexpr` and `try...catch`. Now if the check fails the program terminates. I have left destructors and `clone()` of derived classes `virtual`, in case OP wants to add other layers of children classes. But I agree with you, the code has gotten very ugly and cumbersome; however it should be tighter against exceptions now.